# How to store data permanently in Solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity

I wrote smart contract which has mappings. I stored some key/value pairs in mapping in a transaction. When I try to print mapping in another transaction, the data stored in previous transaction is not permanently stored. How to save data permanently in mapping data structure so that it's reflected in other transactions also?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0 ;
contract mrks
{
 mapping(uint => string) public var ;

 function assign(uint it, string memory str) public
 {
   var[it] = str ;
 }

 function display(uint it) returns(uint) 
 {
   return var[it] ;
 }
}
```

This is the sample code. If I give it=1, str="John" and in another transaction when I give 1 as argument in display function, it's not giving "John" as output .

The question may be silly. Please help me .

Answer (score 2):

You are naming the mapping wrong, `var` is a reserved keyword in Solidity and cannot be used as any data structure's name. The other issue is that the mapping returns `string` but your `display` function returns `int`. I have fixed both issues and below is the resultant code.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0 ;
contract mrks {

 mapping(uint => string) public testMapping;

 function assign(uint it, string memory str) public {
   testMapping[it] = str ;
 }

 function display(uint it) returns(string) {
   return testMapping[it];
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for correcting me and my code.
But my question is if i can store data in mapping permanently or not. To examplify, if i store some key/values in 1st transaction and in other transaction when i view the mapping Data structure , data stored in previous transaction should be reflected. Like we store and retrieve data in database the same way . Can we make it possible  in smart contract also ?
This is my actual doubt.
Thank you

Comment: Yes, mappings are always stored in storage of a contract and it is persistent, meaning that you can access the previous values from mapping within a transaction by providing appropriate key to the mapping structure.

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to get value with another transaction, please ensure the first transaction to store value has already been mined properly.